# Primefaces datatable multiple selection mode - lazy load fetch

Tags: jsf, primefaces

On datatable, I have enabled multiple selection checkbox.
And there is submit button, on actionlistener, I'm getting duplicate records as selected items.

For ex., On first page it is 5 records and total number of records are 10, then the first page records gets replicated twice and results in 10 records, which should be restricted to 5 records.

Following is the code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable id="sampleDataTable" var="_task" value="#{myBean.lazyModelTasks}"
             styleClass="dataTable" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks}"
             paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="5" widgetVar="dataTab"             
             paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
             lazy="true"  selection="#{myBean.selectedItems}" 
             emptyMessage="No Search Results found !">  

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:15px;">  
        <f:facet name="header"> 
        <h:outputText value="Sno" /> 
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable> 

 <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Select" update="#{rerenderid}"
  actionListener="#{myBean.addSelectedItems}" oncomplete="#{onlinkclick}">
  <f:attribute name="selectedItems" value="#{myBean.selectedItems}"/>
 </p:commandButton>
```

**Managed Bean code:**

```
 public void addExternalRecipients(ActionEvent event) { 
      //THIS GIVES ME 10 RECORDS, THOUGH THERE ARE ONLY 5 RECORDS AT THAT INSTANCE
      this.selectedItems = (Address[])   
                         event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selectedItems"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the solution, but you don't need to use the event to get the selected items, I assume you have this in your managed bean:

```
private Address[] selectedItems;
```

You should also put selectionMode="multiple" on the datatable and not on the column like you are doing, like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="sampleDataTable" var="_task" value="#{myBean.lazyModelTasks}"
             styleClass="dataTable" paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks}"
             paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="5" widgetVar="dataTab"             
             paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
             lazy="true"  selection="#{myBean.selectedItems}" 
             selectionMode="multiple" <!--to make multiple rows selected -->
             emptyMessage="No Search Results found !">
```

Then, no need to add an actionevent, the selected entities will be set on your managed bean automatically. When you do a submit (or an ajax call) you should get the correct number of selected entities.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was like that with old primefaces versions, but in todays' eyes this answer does not answer the question correctly. selectionMode="multiple" enables to select rows. The question asks for checkbox selection. This writing this comment for people who come across this question like me :)